# Returning duplicates in a sequence

Tags: clojure, duplicates, sequence

The best I could come up with was:

```
(defn dups [seq]
  (map (fn [[id freq]] id) 
       (filter (fn [[id freq]] (> freq 1))
               (frequencies seq))))
```

Is there a more concise way?

Comment: I like your solution but would simply replace (fn [[id freq]] id) with the key function.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
(defn dups [seq]
  (for [[id freq] (frequencies seq)  ;; get the frequencies, destructure
        :when (> freq 1)]            ;; this is the filter condition
   id))                              ;; just need the id, not the frequency
```

Answer (score 18):

```
(map key (remove (comp #{1} val) 
                 (frequencies seq)))
```

Comment: Can you explain what (comp #{1} val) is doing? Thxs.

Comment: (comp #{1} val) basically means (fn [x] (#{1} (val x))) - basically, it tests if the val of the argument is 1 (if it's contained in the set containing the number 1). val here is the count in the frequency pair.

Answer (score 5):

If you'd like to find duplicates based off some property of the items in the list (i.e. it's a list of maps or a list of records/java objects)

```
(defn dups-with-function
  [seq f]
  (->> seq
       (group-by f)
       ; filter out map entries where its value has only 1 item 
       (remove #(= 1 (count (val %))))))

(let [seq [{:attribute    :one
            :other-things :bob}
           {:attribute    :one
            :other-things :smith}
           {:attribute    :two
            :other-things :blah}]]
  (dups-with-function seq :attribute))
```

outputs:

```
 ([:one
   [{:attribute :one, :other-things :bob}
    {:attribute :one, :other-things :smith}]])
```

If you have a list of java objects and you want to find all the ones with duplicate first names:

```
(dups-with-function my-list #(.getFirstName %))
```

Comment: Thanks for adding your answer to my question: "Returning duplicates at key x in a sequence of maps" ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Minimal filter and frequencies oneliner that does the job:

```
(filter #(< 1 ((frequencies col) %)) col)
```

However it performs poorly on large data. You will have to help the compiler by saying:

```
(let [ freqs (frequencies col) ]
  (filter #(< 1 (freqs %)) col))
```

Comment: Could you kindly explain how/why this helps the compiler?

Comment: By putting the frequencies calculation in the lexical context let clause you force evaluation once first and not for every item in the collection (which you could hope that the compiler should be able to detect and avoid).

Answer (score 1):

[`some`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/some) is the perfect function for this.

```clj
(defn dups [coll]
  (some (fn [[k v]] (when (< 1 v) k))
    (frequencies coll)))
```

However, it basically does the same as the list comprehension.